# How do I prevent TDataSet.Next from leaking memory?

Tags: delphi

I am using a [TDataSet](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TDataSet) that needs to be positioned to the current record.
However, everytime I do `TDataSet.Next()`, the next record is loaded into memory and is never freed. But going to that record again will reload it, resulting in a sizable memory leak in the application.
How can I prevent this behavior ?

Thanks !

Comment: Please provide a minimal example top reproduce. Note that TDataSet is an abstract class, so it is necessary to know the actual class you are using.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know the 'memory and is never freed'?

TDataset uses an internal buffer to store the value for the 'current' record. When scrolling through a dataset, this buffer is re-used. The buffer is freed when the dataset is closed. There is no such thing as allocating memory per record loaded.

Other implementations of TDataset may use a different buffering schema which could lead to leaking memory but the standard TDatatset does not.

Comment: Well, every time I call Next(), the RAM usage goes up and never goes down, so something is getting leaked.
For now I just replaced this by using a query but it's very concerning.